# `Performing VCS refresh` hangs

Tags: intellij-idea, svn

When I commit the changes it will always ask for me to wait for `Performing VCS refresh` for a very long time. Is this a known problem?

Comment: I can confirm that I had this problem in 2019.3 and it is resolved in 2019.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-224516. Fix will be included in the nearest update.

Comment: It's 2022 and it's still happening.